# R coxph() In fitter(....) Loglik converged before variable 1 ; beta may be infinite

Tags: r

Estou usando o modelo de regressão Cox, para uma série de dados bem grande (deixo rodando de um dia para o outro). E quando termina, aparece essa mensagem

```
Mensagens de aviso perdidas:
In fitter(X, Y, strats, offset, init, control, weights = weights,  :
  Loglik converged before variable  1 ; beta may be infinite.
```

Alguém já teve esse problema? Ou sabe como resolver?

Obrigada!

Comment: Sem o resultado de `summary(modelo)` fica difícil dar uma causa exata para este erro. De cara, eu olharia quais foram os valores estimados para os betas. Eu chuto que ficaram altos. Aí, ao fazer `exp(beta)` eles ficariam mais altos ainda, fazendo com o que a função `fitter` te informe que `beta may be infinite`.

Comment: É que eu tenho um "array(NA,c(360,181,29))", que são completados nesse loop bem grande. O que até eu indicaria que são somente em alguns pontos e não em todos, que estão apresentando esse erro.
Mas mesmo assim, nesse seu chute, vc indicaria a partir de quanto um valor alto? 
Eu estou rodando de novo, e vou salvar uma tabela com todos os valores de beta, assim analiso mais detalhadamente.

Comment: Cada caso é um caso na hora de dizer se os betas são altos. Se, por exemplo, a estimativa foi `10`, então `exp(10) = 22026`. Isso significa que o risco associado aumenta em 22 mil vezes, o que talvez seja exagerado neste caso. Como não sei o que é a variável 1 e não sei qual risco está sendo calculado, é impossível dar uma resposta. Se a variável 1 for sexo, é possível que homens tenham 22 mil vezes mais chance de morrerem do que mulheres? É improvável. Por outro lado, se a variável 1 for uso frequente de heroína, talvez o resultado faça sentido. Faltam informações para uma opinião acertada.

Comment: Eu estou usando para previsões climáticas (exemplo, http://www.cnpma.embrapa.br/climapest/workshop/anais/trabalhos/T050.pdf). Mesmo assim, pelo que estou vendo dos valores de beta gerados, estão entre -1 e 1. Não sei, mas talvez não seja nessa linha de ''problema'' o erro apresentado..